# Want to read from a particular offset of a file from internet using Python3

Tags: python, http, python-3.x

I want to read a file on internet from a particular offset in python.
Like in normal file handler (return by open()) we have a seek() api.
Is there any way of doing this when reading from network.

```
import urllib.request
g = urllib.request.urlopen('http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt')
g.seek(20)
f=g.read(100)
print(f)
```

I tried the following but it **obviosuly** gave error

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Probably you can do only `read(20)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Range` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) (only if the server supports it):

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt',
                             headers={'Range': 'bytes=20-'})
g = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
f = g.read(100)
print(f)
```

But not all server support `Range`. You should check response header. If server does not support it, you should skip bytes by read them.

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request('http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt',
                             headers={'Range': 'bytes=20-'})
g = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
if 'Content-Range' not in g.info(): # <-----
# OR  if g.status != http.client.PARTIAL_CONTENT
    g.read(20)                      # <-----
f = g.read(100)
print(f)
```

Comment: Is the Range field is added in the HTTP head of the request?